# Why does our favicon look similar to "beta" SE sites'?

Tags: discussion, design

Not that it bothers me too much, but I always thought U&L was still in beta because of the favicon. It has the same design as all beta SE sites.

Was this a coincidence? Or on purpose?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the same concept, although it does look different -- the beta icons are "sketchy", like:

[BCG sketchy icon http://so.mrozekma.com/bcg-sketchy-icon.png](http://so.mrozekma.com/bcg-sketchy-icon.png)

Ours is the same layout, without the sketchy theme; [Wordpress](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) is another site with a letter-based icon:

[Our icon http://sstatic.net/unix/img/apple-touch-icon.png](http://sstatic.net/unix/img/apple-touch-icon.png)
[Wordpress' icon http://sstatic.net/wordpress/img/apple-touch-icon.png](http://sstatic.net/wordpress/img/apple-touch-icon.png)

I never really cared for it, but I think [Jin](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/3/jin) just had trouble coming up with a graphic that would represent the site well and look good in a small format. If anyone has any ideas I suspect we can get a new one made (trying to find out)

Comment: I don't NOT like the favicon, just wondered. But if it would be possible to design another, we should have a little contest on meta.

Comment: @MaxMackie: I actually like it a lot.

Comment: Note: I think a much better comparison would be those same icons in 10x10 or however tiny the favicon is supposed to be

Comment: How about a penguin? Or the FreeBSD devil? Both?

Comment: @Kevin It's hard to do stuff like that since we allow all \*nix-like OSes here. The [first design](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/337/design-ideas-for-unix-and-linux-site-updated) tried to stuff a bunch of mascots into the header, but people didn't like it and there were some missing. I think a penguin would be good, but I use Linux so I'm biased a bit

Comment: Why not have a random favicon each time you load the page.... it might be a tad annoying to implement, but it could switch between GNU, Tux, etc...

Answer (score 1):

I kind of like the [license plate](https://store.opengroup.org/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=29), if we can have the rights. It's not square, which may be a problem.

Comment: Right now, the U and the L are legible in the favicon. At 16x16 or 32x32, I can scarcely make out what it is supposed to say.

Answer (score 1):

The penguin is by far the [most popular](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&q=linux+favicon&qscrl=1&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&authuser=0&ei=LqodT7vVDoq3rAfAx7jWDQ&biw=1116&bih=868&sei=MKodT8T_C8PqrQeKluybDA#q=linux+favicon&um=1&hl=en&client=ubuntu&channel=cs&qscrl=1&authuser=0&tbm=isch&source=lnt&tbs=isz:i&sa=X&ei=MKodT_PFHIuyrAfWoIHTDQ&ved=0CA4QpwUoAw&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=bea2cd499ca842d7&biw=1116&bih=868) (and recognizable) representation of Linux. Although it doesn't *quite* capture the UNIX idea, linux is the currently most widely-used unix (needs citation :P).

Maybe a penguin on top of the (color-shifted) stack-exchange bubble?

[image: http://sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/favicon.ico]
+ [image] = ?

Comment: Maybe a penguin on top the the stack-exchange bubble?

Answer (score 1):

I'm no designer, but I thing the logo would gain if it had an X in it. U-L-X looks more "unixy" than U-L.

Comment: Maye they didn't take an X because UX (User Experience SE) alrady has an X in it